# find the number of distinct terms in the given expansion

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> find the distinct number of terms in the expansion of                          $(x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n)^3$.
>   this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283603/how-to-find-the-total-number-of-distinct-terms-in-a-certain-expansion) is somewhat related but i'm not sure how to use it in my case.
>   a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. cheers! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination with repetitions, the formula is:

$$\binom{n+r-1}{r}$$
in this case $r=3$ then

$$\binom{n+2}{3}$$

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: I fixed a small typo ($3$ and not $2$ in the last binomial).

Comment: Ok, thank you @ClaudeLeibovici.

Answer (score 1):

Since AsdrubalBeltran gave the answer, I shall just make it more explicit. The total number of distinct terms appearing in your expression is $$N=\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (n+2)$$